# Merging two Images & text on a final image

Tags: swift, uiimage, swift3, core-graphics

What I'm trying to do in Swift is merge two images together, the images I'm merging together is me dragging one image on top of another image with touch gestures. I get the images to composite, BUT the image I dragged on top of the main image does not keep it's position. How do I get it to stay where I placed it for the composite?

Here's my code:

```
extension CIHHatSelectionViewController{
// Return composite image of image2 overlayed on image1
//
func compositeImage(_ image1: UIImage, image2: UIImage, drawText: String, imageView1: CGPoint, imageView2:CGRect) -> UIImage {
    let catPos = (image1.size.height - imageView2.origin.y) - imageView2.height
    let bounds1 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image1.size.width, height: image1.size.height)
    let bounds2 = CGRect(x:imageView2.origin.x, y:catPos, width:imageView2.size.width, height:imageView2.size.height)
    _ = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
    let ctx = CGContext(data: nil,
                        width: image1.cgImage!.width,
                        height: image1.cgImage!.height,
                        bitsPerComponent: image1.cgImage!.bitsPerComponent,
                        bytesPerRow: image1.cgImage!.bytesPerRow,
                        space: image1.cgImage!.colorSpace!,
                        bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)!
    ctx.draw(image1.cgImage!, in: bounds1, byTiling: false)
    ctx.setBlendMode(.normal) // one image over the other
    ctx.draw(image2.cgImage!, in: bounds2, byTiling: false)

    let finalImage = textToImage(drawText, inImage: UIImage(cgImage: ctx.makeImage()!), atPoint: imageView1)
    return finalImage
}
```